# Spark DF CacheTable method. Will it save data to disk?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a spark program where we are going to read 100 million records from Database.

We are reading data from JDBC and creating a DF. I want to cache the DF since it will be used in multiple iterations and calculations.

My Question is if i use DF cachetable() , the data will be saved in memory only. Since DB read is expensive i dont want to read it again in case of failure

In RDD persist function we have option of saving RDD to disk? can we do that in Dataframe cachetable? I dont want to lose optimizations of cachetable also

Answer (score 0):

It will use `MEMORY_AND_DISK`:

> def cache(): Dataset.this.type
>
> Persist this Dataset with the default storage level (MEMORY_AND_DISK).

Comment: I was thinking of using cachetable which has some optimizations. But that is specified to save in memory.                                                                          https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext                                                                                      def
cacheTable(tableName: String): Unit
Caches the specified table in-memory.
Since
1.3.0